# Makefile: target with intermediate prerequisites gets rebuilt every time

Tags: makefile

I am using [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org) to output a Word document `out.docx` from a number of Mardown source files `file1.md file2.md ...`. However, these Markdown files need to be pre-processed before they can be concatenated and converted to Word. I am using GNU `make` for this:

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.md)
TMP := $(patsubst %.md,%.tmp, $(SRC))

.INTERMEDIATE : $(TMP)

out.docx : $(TMP)
        pandoc -o $@ file1.tmp file2.tmp ... -f markdown

%.tmp : %.md
        pandoc -o $@ $< --filter=...
```

Now, I only want `out.docx` to be rebuilt when the source files `$(SRC)` change. However, since the intermediate files `$(TMP)` are deleted at the end of each build, `make` thinks out.docx needs to be rebuilt every single time. Using `$(SRC)` instead of `$(TMP)` in the prerequisites for `out.docx` will not work, of course, because according to [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules):

> `make` will not consider non-terminal match-anything rules (i.e., ‘%:’)
>   when searching for a rule to build a prerequisite of an implicit rule.

So how can I optimize this build and not have it run when not necessary?

Comment: The files in `$(TMP)` are not intermediate files and will not be deleted automatically by make.  You can see they are not intermediate, because you list them explicitily as prerequisites of the `out.docx` target.  That explicit listing is sufficient to prevent them from being considered intermedate.  If they are being deleted there's something different about your actual makefile from what you've shown us here and that thing is causing your problems.  Using the makefile above, the `.tmp` files are not considered intermediate or deleted.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I explicitly declared `.INTERMEDIATE : $(TMP)`

Comment: The thing is, I don't need the $(TMP) files for anything else, so I'd rather have them deleted, *but* I want the target to be built only when the $(SRC) files change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the examples you provide actually show the problem.  There must be something different about your real situation than what you show here because the makefile you show here will work as you expect.  I don't have `pandoc` installed so I substituted `touch` and it works fine:

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.md)
TMP := $(patsubst %.md,%.tmp,$(SRC))

.INTERMEDIATE: $(TMP)

out.docx: $(TMP)
        touch $@

%.tmp: %.md
        touch $@
```

Now:

```
$ touch foo.md bar.md biz.md

$ make
touch bar.tmp
touch biz.tmp
touch foo.tmp
touch out.docx
rm foo.tmp bar.tmp biz.tmp

$ make
make: 'out.docx' is up to date.

$ touch biz.md

$ make
touch bar.tmp
touch biz.tmp
touch foo.tmp
touch out.docx
rm foo.tmp bar.tmp biz.tmp
```

You can run `make -d` (redirect the output for later investigation) to see why make thinks that `out.docx` is out of date.

Comment: Thank you. I made a typo in one of the order-only prerequisites I was using, which caused `make` to think everything was out-of-date every time.